# Spring boot with maven multi module project

Tags: spring-boot, maven-module

I have a maven multi module project designed like the first answer in following SO post:
[Multi-module maven with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579692/multi-module-maven-with-spring-boot)

Now I want a common maven module that can contain some models to be used by multiple microservices. If I make this common project as a child of the first level parent pom (so that all dependencies injected by boot like jpa, jackson etc are available to common), then STS/Spring is detecting it as a boot application and complains about no Main class on maven build.

Can someone suggest how I can achieve this?

Current Code:

parent pom.xml: (Only relevant parts included)

```xml
    <project>
    <name>...</name>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>...</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>Brixton.M3</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    </project>
```

child (common module) pom.xml (only relevant parts), not to be boot app:

```xml
    <project>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <name>...</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
        <version>...</version>
    </parent>

    </project>
```

Answer (score 11):

I don't have all the details regarding your project but my best guess is that the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` is defined on the parent (or you are using the `spring-boot-starter-parent` in your root pom). This effectively ask the build to package your module as a Spring Boot app (which is not what you want).

STS probably looks for that hint to figure out if a module contains a Spring Boot application or not. Maybe it would be nicer if it looks for a main class annotated with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` (or `SpringBootApplication`).

You can fix the problem easily (from the build side) by specifying the [skip property of the repackage goal](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html)

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

If STS still picks up the module as a Spring Boot app, I'd create [an issue in their tracker](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried as you suggested but it did now help. Added following section to child pom: `<build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <goals>
       <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
       <skip>true</skip>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>` This however reduced my build time as the common modules are not repackaged as executable jars

Comment: I am afraid, I can't help you without more details. I am just guessing at this point.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was a resolution for my problem with spring-boot not seeing mainClass property :D

Answer (score 0):

Normally, Spring Boot won't start a web container if it's not present in the module.
I would suggest you to analyse your dendencies using the command

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

One more brute-force way of ensuring is use this configuration in your application.properties

```
spring.main.web-environment=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to fix this:

1. You can add the skip property like **@Stephane Nicoll** mentioned. However, this will completely ignore the test cases inside that module. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/it-skip.html
2. Another option is to add a classifier property to make a separate executable jar out of this module. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-classifier.html

   ```
   <executions>
             <execution>
               <id>repackage</id>
               <goals>
                 <goal>repackage</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                 <classifier>exec</classifier>
               </configuration>
             </execution>
   ```

This fix will make sure the dependent module get its required jar and the source module will still be an executable one.